# Should we bother to tag questions with [windows-phone] or [windows-phone-7]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, tags

As questions are added to the site, tags such as [windows-phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone), [windows-phone-7](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7), and [windows-phone-7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5) are appearing.

Is [windows-phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) redundant given the nature of the site? If so, what about [windows-phone-7](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) and more specific versions?

Answer (score 6):

We are on the `windows phone` site, so repeating it in a tag as`windows-phone` adds *nothing*.

I would suggest tagging them by their code name, like `mango`, `tango` and so on...

Comment: Ok, but only the comercial name of version, not the version indeed. We need to avoid posts tagging build numbers like 7720, 8107 and 8773.

Answer (score 4):

Note that tagging every question with the version the user has is also going to be pure noise.  Some features, bugs, etc. will undoubtedly carry across versions; the version the user has is irrelevant in most cases.

As such, on the Android site we only put version tags on questions that need them:

- Questions about new functionality in a new version
- Questions about bugs only found in one version
- Questions about upgrading from one version to another (both tags applied)

And so on.  I suggest we do the same here.

Comment: Excellent point - incidentally, this is why I blacklisted (rather than synonymizing) the [windows-phone-<version>] tags - because so many new users start typing "windows-phone" when choosing tags, using it as a prefix tends to encourage their use.

Answer (score 1):

We've blacklisted any tags beginning with "windows-phone" - that should apply to pretty much every question and most tags on the site, so it's unnecessary.

I've made [mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mango) and [7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango) synonyms - please do likewise for other versions as-needed.

Comment: What is the most appropriate way to ping valued associates about such synonyms requests? As we can't really get these of the ground ourselves I think. Or do we just post a new [retag-request] meta question? (At least as long as there are no pro-term moderators)

Comment: Yes, post a [synonym-request] here on meta.

Comment: @Shog9 If we end up allowing *Windows Mobile* questions, should we be able to differentiate between windows mobile and windows phone?

Comment: @Joe: since WP started with Version 7, using the WM version should suffice. And probably *mentioning in the post* that it's about WM.

Comment: works for me, thanks

Comment: can a whitelist of exceptions (like [windowsphone.com]) be nested inside the blacklist?

Answer (score 1):

As Windows Phone 8 (or whatever it's going to be called) is going to be a major upgrade and likely to address a lot of the current deficiencies in the OS, with more APIs making more things possible, some Q&As are likely to be irrelevant at best and confusing for new users at worst, once it comes out.

As nobody here can know or disclose the changes in WP8 at this stage, it may be necessary to tag these questions once it comes out with WP7, in my opinion.

Comment: It can always be tagged "apollo" just as we have a couple of questions tagged "mango"

Comment: @Joe: So do you expect new users to know that the question is not relevant to older versions of the OS?  It would make much more sense to re-tag old questions where the issue is no longer relevant, as WP becomes less restrictive, and more popular and in its next iteration (hopefully).

Comment: No, I don't expect them too. However, if we NEED to tag older questions (or re-tag new ones in some cases) all I am saying is we can use the codename (Mango, Tango, Apollo) using Windows-Phone-X is verbose. we know it is winPhone. We could even use v7, v7.5 v8 if we wanted. I would just rather not use the windows-phone syntax

Comment: @Joe: That was not what my answer was about (and I suggested `WP7`, and I am don't think all users will know the codenames), so I do not know what you are disagreeing with enough to downvote something which seems logical to me.

Comment: You are assuming I downvoted it :) I guess I mis-read it, but the DV wasn't me

Answer (score 0):

Tags that don't add anything should not be used.

you can use the "7.5-mango" or "mango" tag for questions that are related to a specific update but since almost every device (soon to be every since microsoft is already discontinueing the 7.0 marketplace) is a mango device it doesn't add anything.

Maybe as soon as Tango hits we can get Tango specific questions. but how long does it take for these tags to be old and become main stream?