# Should we encourage people to tag their questions with their handset model and network?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So many features can be locked out either by the handset manufacturer, or by the network; Rather than having to word answers along the lines of "[On some handsets...](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/81/106)", should we instead encourage askers to tag with their handset make/model and/or network, eg `[htc-titan] [orange-uk]`

Answer (score 7):

I think one of The best windows phone features is that most functionality is equal on all devices.

By adding handset model or operator tags youll create a lot of similar questions where people have a general windows phone question but make the question to specific for their handset or operator.

What are the features that differ from brand or operator?
I can only think of tethering and brand specific apps

Comment: I find the available options and vendor apps differ quite a bit between my Titan, and my wife's Lumia; I personally doubt that someone searching for the answer would be put off by it being tagged for a different device

Comment: I think that 90+% of the questions are not brand specific so adding these tags to all questions would only cause confusion. If there is a question on specific vendor apps for example i think it is ok to add tags

Comment: Taking http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/195/106 as an example, the handset that *was* tagged (until you removed it) does have a vendor specific app that claims to do what is asked; although it doesn't actually work properly.

Comment: He did tag a handset but the question was a general question that could be asked for each windows phone device. I'd say split the answer in 2 parts like "No this is not possible except for when you have a HTC Titan then there is App xyz that can do this for you".  By answering in that way the Question is generic but the answer answers every case for special devices aswell.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two questions I can think of that would have this problem.

1. How do I enable Internet Sharing?
2. Where can I access Visual Voicemail?

There may be more, but I can't think of any. For the most part the OS is very very similar across network/models and I think having the tags is not going to be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that a carrier tag would fall under "too localised"?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with GeertvdC.  The reasoning is the same as in [Should we bother to tag questions with [windows-phone] or [windows-phone-7]?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/66):

Tagging every question with the device the user has is going to be pure noise.  Most features, bugs, etc. will undoubtedly carry across devices; the device the user has is irrelevant in most cases.

As such, on the Android site we only put version tags on questions that need them:

```
- Questions about functionality specific to a (set of) device(s)
- Questions about bugs only found on one (set of) device(s)
- Questions about restoring a backup from one device on another (both tags applied)
```

And so on.  I suggest we do the same here.

Answer (score 0):

I think device tags should only be added when the problem is specific to that device, because otherwise they only add unnecessary noise to the question. If I'm asking something about the Messaging Hub, it is most likely that the device I have will not matter at all.

The network tags don't really work well as a tag on their own, which makes it kind of a meta tag; I don't see any use in having them for that occasional question about X being restricted by  network Y, but other than that (and the examples of other answers here) I don't see much occasions to use them so they probably shouldn't be used.