# How can we avoid people using the [wp7.5-mango] tag

Tags: discussion

If you look at tag usage the [wp7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp7.5-mango) is used far the most of all tags and in my opinion it is used in a wrong way.

when you look at the [list](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango) of questions tagged with this tag most of them are just general questions that can apply for all versions of Windows Phone.

examples:

- How do we have seperate notifications for different email accounts?
- Where is the forward button in Internet Explorer?
- How can I switch audio output from A2DP to jack?

in [this discussion](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-bother-to-tag-questions-with-windows-phone-or-windows-phone-7) on meta we decided that tagging with Windows Phone is useless and i would suggest adding [wp7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp7.5-mango) is also quite useless except for some egde cases (All windows phone do run mango or can run mango) so what is the use of this tag?

I already removed the tag from quite some questions that were just general windows phone questions so should i keep doing it or not?

Comment: See my answer below, but I think the tag is fine for "Where is the forward button in Internet Explorer?". The forward button was removed in Mango, and as such it is worth calling out, no?

Comment: Joe, mango was released last october and even the marketplace will be closed for non mango phones. EVERYONE is or should be running mango so what does the tag add to that question if you think like that. The answer can be related to mango but the question isnt imo

Comment: Where did you see that the marketplace would be closed for non mango phones?

Comment: When Tango ships (and Apollo) wouldn't we want to be able to tag by version? What does Android.SE do for the different version?

Comment: @joe here is the link stating non mango marketplace will be shut down: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/04/24/two-marketplace-changes-and-how-they-affect-you.aspx

Comment: Also comparing with Android maybe isn't the best comparison since there is a lot of fragmentation on the Android market. Every phone will upgrade to tango. for Apollo we still have to wait what will happen there.

Comment: I can agree with that

Comment: @TomWijsman & GeertvdC - Going by the comments above, and anecdotal evidence; should we scratch the tag for now? I can't see any questions that actually **are** specific to Mango. It seems like the tag can be removed until Apollo or Tango ships, and there is a difference http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the tag wiki excerpt to instruct the user when to use the tag.**

When people want to select a tag, they get a list of some tags *with tag wiki excerpts* shown to them. If you want to tell someone when (not) to show a certain tag, the excerpt is the best way to let them know.

Currently it says:

> version 7.5 of the Windows Phone operating system.

I would propose changing it to something like:

> version 7.5 of the Windows Phone OS. Use this tag when your question is specific to this version.

Perhaps its wording could be better, but its the idea that counts.

Comment: ok my proposal for the excerpt is: "version 7.5 of the Windows Phone OS. Use this tag for questions that are specific to this version of the OS or problems regarding upgrades from or to this version."

Comment: @GeertvdC: Not sure whether we could fit that, we could cut some weasel words though. I guess we should just go ahead and apply it, given that it's a quite visible tag we'll hear it soon enough if it's not OK. Shorter version: `version 7.5 of the Windows Phone OS. Use for questions specific to this version or problems regarding upgrades from/to this version.`

Comment: i've added your shorter version to the excerpt

Answer (score 2):

I thought the same thing this morning. I feel like the [7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango) tag is way over used, and should only be used when something only applies to that build (copy/paste, multitasking, and what not)

I don't want to scratch the tag, an I think just coaching people will eventually do the trick. It may take a decent amount of effort at first, but After a month I hope things will get better.

What I imagine is the problem now is that people just don't know what tags to use, so they default to that. For now I say we just keep up with removing the tag, and commenting as to why.

[Where is the forward button in Internet Explorer?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/214/where-is-the-forward-button-in-internet-explorer) is a great question to show how the tag is appropriate. Functionality that was there in the original build was removed in Mango, and such the tag is a perfect fit.