# How should we form tags for specific WP versions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed, that the tags for questions, regarding a specific OS version are not named consistently. We have [7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango)<sup>1</sup>, [7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.8), [wp7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp7.5) and [7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.x). For Windows Phone 8 we have [8.0-apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.0-apollo) and [wp8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp8)

I think a pure number like *7.0*, *7.5* and *7.8* should be preferred. It should be clear, that we are talking about windows phone. Since I do not have enought reputation to suggest tag synonyms nor create tags and I did not found a question here on meta regarding this topic, I want to discuss this with you.

## Reform the tags

Here are my suggestions:

- All questions regarding a *specific OS* should go to [wp7](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp7) and [wp8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp8)
- Questions regarding a specific update should go to [7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5), [7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.8), ...

And for the existing tags, I think, some should be renamed:

- [7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango) > [7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5)
- [wp7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp7.5) > [7.5](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5)
- [7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.x) > [windows-phone-7](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) <sup>2</sup>
- [wp8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp8) > [windows-phone-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)
- [8.0-apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.0-apollo) > [windows-phone-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)

<sup>1</sup><sub><sup>[Note](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-we-avoid-people-using-the-wp7-5-mango-tag)</sup></sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub><sup>Questions regarding the update progress in general should go to [update](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update).</sup></sub>

## Windows Phone version numbers

There has been some confusion about versions in the comments an the answers. This should only be a little note on version numbers for Windows Phone, leading me towards the previously described proposal:

Actually there are three ways to describe a version:

1. The "official" or "end-user" version number (e.g. *7.5*, *7.8*)
2. The codename (*mango*, *tango*, *apollo*, *NoDo*, ...)
3. The "internal" version number (e.g. *7.10.8862.144* for WP 7.8 - note that the internal number actually starts with *7.10*!)

I think, we should only focus on the first two points, because they are what's actually provided to the end-user. The update *7.8* actually consists out of multiple updates (at least 3 for me) and one bug fix. The latest version is *7.10.8862.144* and is the only one provided in the version history below. *Mango* or *7.5* also required multiple updates. However there's allways a change in the minor version number. I think this is what we should focus on. The codenames as tag synonyms and the official version number as usual tags.

Official sources:

- [Update History for Windows Phone 7](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/update-history)
- [Update History for Windows Phone 8](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history)

Comment: Agreed. But how about an specific version, like Portico? Maybe we can use the OS version and a tag with this name too, separately.

Comment: I would not tag them seperately. What's the advantage, of (e.g.) tagging a question as *7.5* AND *mango*? I'd rather suggest using codenames as tag synonyms... ;)

Comment: Also, what's Portico? The code name for the versions isn't that well known outside of development circles - I'd go along with the proposal, and suggest it should be the pure version number in the "Software" line of the about line (e.g. 7.8; not 7.10.8862.144)

Comment: I totally agree with @RowlandShaw. If we really want/need codename-tags, then I suggest creating them as tag syonyms.

Comment: @Aschratt I can see a problem with calling WP Mango and Tango as 7.5. We need this information sometimes. Like Nokia Counter., it only run in Tango and above, as far as I know. And Rowland, actually many non dev people call this by its codename. In fact I really don't know the exact version number of Mango, Tango, Portico and so on. But I understood you point.

Comment: One other thing, I'd consider [7.x] as for *any* version of 7, but not 8; with this in mind, should wp8/8.0-apollo become [8.x], rather than duplicate the windows-phone portion?

Comment: @VitorCanova I'd prefer to be inclusive with our audience. My wife has a Windows Phone, and she would have no idea if it is running mango/tango/jellybean/portico/collonade/apollo/daphne. She does know that she is running 7.5, and is waiting to update to 7.8 though.

Comment: @VitorCanova I think Tango is probably a special case that can be ignored. Time will tell of course if a similar release happens, but I don't think Tango deserves its own tag.

Comment: I liked the [7.x] idea. I think I'm not so "open minded" right now. You are all right about that people don't know about name version. ;)

Comment: Due the confusion with version numbers I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest we drop the code names from all of the tags. Now that time has passed since their common usage, it looks incorrect to see 8.0apollo or 7.5mango. It is clear enough to mention just the number or wp8.

I actually prefer the wpX.X syntax as most enthusiast podasts use that format as well.

**ADDITIONALLY:** Since this post has started there has not been a real need to create GDR1, GDR2 or GDR3 tags for the additional functionality that these updates give to WP8. It seems ridiculous to keep the codenames on the tags.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest looking at Android Stack Exchange:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/2.3-gingerbread/synonyms
- https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/4.0-ice-cream-sandwich/synonyms
- https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/4.1-jelly-bean/synonyms

They seem to use the following format:

- Tag Name: TwoDigitVersion-CodeName
- Synonyms: TwoDigitVersion, CodeName, OS-TwoDigitVersion

Example:

- Tag Name: 4.1-jelly-bean
- Synonyms: 4.1, jelly-bean, android-4.1

They do not seem have have a catch all tag for the OS major version e.g. there is no '4' or 'android-4' tag. So I would suggest that [7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.x) and [wp8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp8) are overkill and not needed. There is no harm in tagging a generic Windows Phone 7 question as [7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.8).

A difference is that for Android the code name is also a marketing name, whereas (as far as I can see) Microsoft seems to drop the code name once released, so as per the comments, a lot of people don't know the code names.

If you look on Super User, they do not include the code names at all in their Windows Tags:

- https://superuser.com/tags/windows-vista/synonyms
- https://superuser.com/tags/windows-8/synonyms

So, I would actually suggest removing the code names all together. The code name doesn't actually provide any useful information, Microsoft isn't using it, and if people know the code name then they know the actual two-digit version number. Perhaps Tango is a special case as it was 7.5, but really Tango was a very minor and short lived update, its new features were better supported by a separate tag [low-end-devices](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-end-devices).

So I would suggest the following

- Tag Name*: Two-digit OS version e.g. [7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.8)
- Synonyms*: <strike>OS-TwoDigitVersion e.g. [windows-phone-7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.8)</strike> **tags in this format seem to be [banned](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8/295)**
- Delete/Rename the code name tags e.g. [8.0-apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.0-apollo) and [apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apollo)
- Remove the OS catch all tag e.g. [7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.x) and [wp8].

*perhaps these two could be swapped—as I new user I would probably first try to tag it as [windows-phone-7.8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.8).

Comment: I also don't think we actually need the codenames. That's why I would suggest them as synonyms. I've also updated the question.

Comment: Even as a synonym I am not sure that they are actually needed. To me, Windows Phone code names are the names for the pre-release version, the code name doesn't actually get released or marketed to the user, so following the example by Super User of not using them for Windows tags makes sense.

Comment: What about in the case of Lumia Black, which included WP8 Update 3 along with Nokia specific updates?

Comment: @Arabella Lumia Black is a shipping name for a convrete set of features. You need to remember that Lumia Black's codename was Bittersweet Shimmer (orange). It makes sense to have tags for the common shipping names of a product, like black, but not to the codenames, which become irrelevant with time. Shipping names like Lumia Black can always be referenced to mean the same thing. Codenames can be reused (especially at Microsoft).

Comment: @caschw I see your point. It would stand to reason that the codenames be used before the product is released because genuine questions may come up during the testing period, but then to do a clean up after release to ensure the questions are tagged with the release name. Sounds like a lot of work though.

Comment: @Arabella I don't think we need to tag rumors or pre-release codenames

Answer (score 2):

Actually we do need the codenames, but as probably as separate tags. For example MS is now making Windows Phone Blue available for testing to selected users. We still don't know if it's going to be Windows Phone 8.1 or if they are going to create some other name.

The system needs to be flexible enough so it can accompany Microsoft's name changes and schemes. Things are going to change as Microsoft will combine Windows Phone and Big Windows (RT/Pr) resources and dev teams.