# What's with the Windows-8 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[windows-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) seems to being used for all the wrong reasons. There only seems to be a handful of questions which are actually about the Windows 8 (desktop).

What should we do with this tag?

The questions relating to the phone should be re-tagged see [How should we form tags for specific WP versions?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-form-tags-for-specific-wp-versions)

Comment: What did you suggest? Make it a synonym or block? I know we can do the previous but don't know about the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest re-tagging all the appropriate questions to [8.0-apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.0-apollo) (which perhaps should be [renamed](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-form-tags-for-specific-wp-versions) to [windows-phone-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8) since that has the most votes) and then adding a wiki for [windows-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8).

Comment: I agree, especially with renaming the 8.0 Apollo tags. It really bugs me!

Comment: I tried to add 'windows-phone-8' but: Failed to propose synonym:

The tag windows-phone-8 is banned

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: Not sure where that list is maintained. I will have to ask another mod.

Comment: I have cleaned up the [windows-8] tag

Comment: Found out why is was banned http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/8/295

Comment: I really can't agree with that logic. The operating systems are branded as Windows Phone 7.5. I would at least prefer WP 7.5, WP 7.1, WP 8 than the "code name" tags. Should we start a new meta based on new info?

Comment: Already have your post in http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-form-tags-for-specific-wp-versions and I have added it as a featured question. So let that brew for a little bit longer.