# Should we rename Windows-10 tag to windows-10-pc?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) is supposed to be used for questions related to Windows-10 PC as said it's usage guidance.

> Use this tag for questions about connecting your Windows phone to a
>   Windows 10 PC. For questions about running Windows 10 Mobile, please
>   see windows-10-mobile.

However recently I edited about more than 10 questions with that tag, an example is [this one](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/backed-up-text-messages-are-duplicated-after-windows-10-install). In these questions these [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) is used for [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile).

10 questions is a large number here as it is about 20% of the total questions in that tag to represent the mobile version of the operating system.

---

**Update** : What I am trying to say is I think with the unified windows approach people think it is correct to use windows-10 tag for the mobile OS which is not as it deals with problems of Windows phones with windows 10 **desktop OS**. I fell that renaming [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) to [windows-10-pc](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-pc) will end this confusion.

---

Should we rename this tag to windows-10-pc?

Answer (score 3):

I see where you're coming from with this suggestion. The problem is that people start typing "windows" into the tag box, see [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) in the list and think "close enough". Most new users don't bother to read the wiki excerpts. We had the exact same problem with people tagging WP8 questions as [windows-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) because that was the first suggestion in the tag box and because "windows-phone-8" and "windows-phone-7" tags were banned. [I raised that issue](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/1401) almost two years ago, but unfortunately it didn't go anywhere. I see this question as closely related, and perhaps if we do get a discussion going here we can address that older one as well. Hit two birds with one stone, so to say.

I respectfully disagree with **Rowland** about renaming [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile) to anything not beginning with "windows". It didn't work with WP8.x, it's not going to work now. What's needed is ensuring that the tag is first in the list of suggestions when people start typing in "windows". I'm not 100% clear on how tags are ordered, but if it's alphabetical, then renaming to [windows-10-pc](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-pc) might actually work, because "pc" comes after "mobile". It's not 100% technically correct, but in the interest of getting questions tagged correctly, I think it's a fair trade-off. As such, and contrary to my initial reaction when reading this suggestion, I find myself in tentative agreement.

Comment: I also agree that if were to decide to rename the windows-10 tag to windows-10-pc then we should rename the other tags such as windows-8 to windows-8-pc so that all the problems will be solved at once.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should rename desktop OS tags as  PC-windows-10, PC-windows-8.1, PC-windows-8 and PC-windows-7. "PC" in the start of tag will make even a new-comer's mind as well to think that tags are useful for only PC-related problems. While mobile OS tags should be Windows-10-mobile, 8.0, 8.1 and 7.x as they are since the site title "Windows Phone" clearly indicates that such tags are referring to the respective versions of Windows Phone OS. Since Windows 10 Mobile is officially called as an edition of Windows 10 therefore its tag should not be renamed to 10.0 or something which might be true if it were called Windows Phone 10. Here I also respectfully disagree @Rowland about renaming windows-10-mobile to anything not beginning with "windows". Or to be more clear we should rename mobile OS tags in their short forms as w10m, wp8.1, wp8, wp7.x and wm6.x.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) relates to questions with syncing a Windows Phone (irrespective of its version) with a PC running Windows 10. Similar to [windows-8.1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1)

The [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile) tag relates to issues with phones running Windows 10 Mobile as installed on their phone, or as updated to the current public release via the Over The Air updates. Similar to [8.1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.1)

If anything, [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile) should be renamed to [10.0](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10.0), or similar.

Comment: Renaming [tag:windows-10-mobile] to [tag:10.0] won't prevent the confusion among **people using windows-10 tag for windows-10-mobile**. This was not a problem with windows8.1 as people used the word wp instead of windows. Now with the windows 10 people have started using this windows tag for mobile version. I believe this is due to people see this windows 10 as a single OS. I think we have to indicate that [tag:windows-10] is different from [tag:windows-10-mobile]and it should be used for questions related to problems in connecting phones with a **desktop OS** in the tag itself.

Comment: I clearly understand what these tags represent. I understand that The windows-10 tag *relates to questions with syncing a Windows Phone (irrespective of its version) with a PC running Windows 10.* I mentioned it's usage guidance in the question itself. **My main concern is people are using windows-10 tag for the mobile version of the OS which is supposed not to be used.** But your answer explains nothing about it. I guess I was not clear in my question. I am sorry for my level of communication.

Comment: Updated my question to be make my point more clear.