# Why can't I create the tag [windowsphone.com]?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

Just added this question:
[What setting up do I need to do for "Find My Phone" to work?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-setting-up-do-i-need-to-do-for-find-my-phone-to-work)

And tried to tag it with a couple of new tags [find-my-phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-my-phone) and [windowsphone.com](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windowsphone.com).

Only the former was allowed. The latter caused this to show:
[image]

Regardless of whether this is a good tag to have (and I would argue it could be useful to collect together questions dealing with services at windowsphone.com), how come it's not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8/131) on [Should we bother to tag questions with [windows-phone] or [windows-phone-7]?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-bother-to-tag-questions-with-windows-phone-or-windows-phone-7) [windows-phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) as been blacklisted. I presume it extends to variants of that spelling.

> We've blacklisted any tags beginning with "windows-phone" - that
>   should apply to pretty much every question and most tags on the site,
>   so it's unnecessary.
>   - Shog9

Comment: can a whitelist of exceptions (like [windowsphone.com]) be nested inside the blacklist?

Comment: @hawbsl We probably could modify the blacklist rule, but how useful is [windowsphone.com] as a tag, anyway? We'd need to see a list of questions that'd benefit from it. There's not much point of trying to make exceptions for just one.